# posix shared memory for multiple clients

Tags: c, posix, semaphore, memory-mapping

I am implementing client server using POSIX shared memory and unnamed semaphores. The server is expected to handle multiple clients concurrently. The code works with single client, but not with multiple client. The POSIX operations are managed with,

```
enum { MAX_MSG = 256 };
enum { CLIENT_SEM,          // semaphore is 1 if server is available for use by client    
       MSG_FOR_DAEMON_SEM,  // semaphore is 1 if shm contains msg for daemon    
       MSG_FOR_CLIENT_SEM,  // semaphore is 1 if shm contains msg for client    
       MSG_FOR_SERVER_SEM,  // semaphore is 1 if shm contains msg for server    
       N_SEMS };

typedef struct {    
    sem_t  sems[N_SEMS]; // semaphore sent for sync   
    pid_t  clientPid;    // pid of current client    
    char   msg[MAX_MSG]; // current message being sent    
    int    max_matrix_size; //max rows a square matrix can have 
}Comm;

// server calls setup_comm with doCreate=1 and creates shared mem of size max_clients * sizeof(Comm) 
// client calls setup_comm with doCreate=0 and in return gets the mmap pointer to the shared memory created by the server 
Comm* setup_comm(const char *shmPosixName, int doCreate, int max_clients);
```

The question is, to handle multiple clients, do we need to maintain an array of Comm structure; that is `Comm[max_clients]` instead of what I am using at present (a single Comm structure)? And for each client, server need to manage the Comm array and return the suitable element from that array to the client. Client in turn will use that block to synchronize the operations over semaphores within the Comm element? Or multiple clients can be handled with single Comm structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a single instance of Comm, then the server plus all clients would share that one struct to do all communication.  That implies sem_wait/sem_post around all accesses, while shuffling the clientPid and the remainder of the struct variables to match the currently active client.

It would seem more straightforward to allocate the array of structs, with the server manipulating the whole range of structs, while each child would only access one of the array elements (granted, it can see them all but would only deal with one).  Then each set of semaphores per Comm element would be used to coordinate communication between the server and a particular client.  The assumption here is the clients have no communication between themselves.